# How to extract ucas and utoc io store container files in unreal engine 5

Tags: unreal-5

I tried to use different programs for this, such as fmodel and UnrealPakViewer, but fmodel does not support ucas and .binka audio files. UnrealPakViewer can open ucas and I can see files in it, but I cant unpack these files.

Files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W5cv3n6cgVFx18W6_A1Rqo350-TeLlCV?usp=sharing